# Epsilon delta proof, choosing inequality side

Tags: epsilon-delta

I have to prove the following using epsilon delta: $$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} x^3+4x^2+4x-1 = -1$$

if $|x+2| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$

Factorizing f(x): $|(x+2)(x^2+2x)| < \varepsilon$

Divide both sides by $|x^2+2x|$ and get: $|x+2| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|x^2+2x|}$.

I have $-\delta < x+2 < \delta$ from $|x+2| < \delta$

I then set $\delta:=1$ and subtract $2$ from all sides: $-3 < x < -1$

I do this to create an upper bound for $x$ and therefore an upper bound for $|x^2+2x|$

How do I know which side of the inequality (-3 or -1) to substitute for $x$ in $\frac{\varepsilon}{|x^2+2x|}$?

Alternatively, if thats the wrong approach, what's the right approach for deciding $\delta$?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why do you want to use one of $-3$ and $-1$ in $|x^2+2x|$?

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing or why you think it would be any use. I suggest you show all the steps with explanation.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to clean it up a bit now, I want to use one of $-3$ and $-1$ to create an upper bound for $|x^2+2x|$ such that $|x+2| |x^2+2x| < \delta * upperBound$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ such that $|x+2|<1$ we have that $|x|<3$, and so, for all $\varepsilon>0$, if $x$ satisfies that $$|x+2|<\min\Big\{1,\sqrt \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \Big\}$$ then $\displaystyle |(x^3+4x^2+4x-1)-(-1)| = |x(x+2)^2| = |x||x+2|^2 < 3 \Big( \sqrt \frac{\varepsilon}{3} \Big)^2 = \varepsilon.$

Comment: Could you elaborate on your scratchwork from $|x||x+2|^2$? Thank you!

Comment: You mean the last inequality?

Comment: Yes, how do you get $\sqrt{\varepsilon/3}$? The more I look at it, the more I think $\delta$ should be minimum of $1$ and $\varepsilon/3$

Comment: If $|x+2| < \min\{1,\varepsilon/3\}$, $|x| < 3$ and $|x+2|^2 < \varepsilon^2/9$, meaning that $|x||x+2|^2 < \varepsilon^2/3$.